# Weighing up the combat benefits of 3 different multi-class builds: Druid/Rogue/Cleric

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing

I will have a dilemma as to where to up my levels and I would like some advice with this.

So far I have taken:

- 3 levels as a Druid (Circle of the Shepherd)
- 3 levels as a Rogue (Mastermind)
- 3 levels as a Cleric (Disciple of Life)

This build has great synergy in **my purpose as the main "support-player" in combat to the party**. My damage output is usually low (the odd Cantrip here and there) but my main function is to help the others e.g. keeping them alive, providing advantage using *Master of Tactics*, and being a damage buffer by using *Warding Bond* as a I have high AC and high HPs. It has been a lot of fun playing this build as I can contribute very effectively to fights.

The drawback so far is that I have not reached the levels where I would get either an Ability Score Increase or a Feat. The next time I go up in level I will get one. **I am planning on taking most of my levels as a Druid from now** on, but I wanted to know if there is **any tactical advantage of taking +1 or +2 levels as a Rogue and Cleric** instead of just leveling as a Druid only.

The way I see it, these are the 3 options I would consider:

**Build 1:** Druid 14, Rogue 3, Cleric 3

**Build 2:** Druid 12, Rogue 4, Cleric 4

**Build 3:** Druid 10, Rogue 5, Cleric 5

**In you can answer this, please compare the Class benefits of the 3 builds and keep in mind my overall goals?**

My overall goal is to be a good "support-player" to my party:

- to keep myself and the party alive
- to be the tank's buffer
- to be the damage-dealers' booster

In our campaign we can use published materials like the *Player's Handbook*, *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* and we are allowed the option of Feats instead of taking ability points.

My current stats are:

STR 8, DEX 19, CON 16, INT 8, WIS 18, CHA 12

[Though I originally asked to refer to the original *three* builds I mentioned, I am happy to receive answers with other combinations - so long as the answer still sticks to the principles of what my overall goals as a support-character in combat for my party.]

Answer (score 12):

## Druid 12/Cleric 5/Rogue 3 probably best but Druid 14/Rogue 3/Cleric 3 has some cool options

Firstly,

### Prioritizing level 6 in druid with conjuring is powerful and advances all your goals.

Before I go into evaluating endgame potential of lvl 20 builds, I would argue your character's next big power spike will be druid level 6.

On Druid 5 you will gain access to level 3 spells to go with your high-level spell slots and one of the signature druid spells, conjure animals. Summoning is a powerful tool.

- It **swings the action economy in your favor**.
- Provides a **buffer between you and enemies**, your tank can take a breather
- You can **order your summons to help** your party providing advantage when needed (advantage -> more damage)
- Enemies will have to waste their actions to deal with your annoying advantage giving critters which keeps your party alive longer.

Of course, that means using your concentration so **warcaster** feat is a powerful option for you to grab, especially with incredibly good stats already.

On druid 6 this becomes much more powerful with **Mighty Summoner** and access to **level 5 spell slots** for more powerful conjure animals.

Now to the individual final builds:

### There is not much to gain from Druid 12/Rogue 4/Cleric 4

This is the heaviest ASI build giving you 5 ASIs in total. However, your ability scores are already incredibly good.

If you adopt the druid conjurer playstyle, you likely take the **warcaster** feat to help with concentration if enemies identify you as a threat but otherwise you don't need much. Your other picks might be **+1 Dex and +1 Wis** and **Observant** if you think that Wisdom 20 is important for your character, otherwise something like **Resilient DEX** and **Tough** (or +2 CON). You might find yourself not using your spells on enemies much and lower wisdom will not debilitating then.

Either way, you don't need many ASIs so no need to optimize for those.

### Druid 14/Rogue 3/Cleric 3 is a good choice

Having access to higher-level spells is always a good thing, however, druid lvl. 7 spells are often more situational than always good.

Depending on your campaign **planeshift** might be an amazing grab or just useless. **Reverse gravity** can be very good but depends on the situation and **mirage arcane** depends on how your DM handles creative uses of illusions.

**Faithful Summons**, your Druid 14 feature could potentially swing a losing battle but requires you to be 0 HP or incapacitated so it is more of a  contingency rather than something you want to use.

If you think these spells will be useful in the high-level portion of your campaign and like the backup of having faithful summons this is not a bad build. It leans away from the usual druid conjuration strategy that can start falling off in late-game when enemies have powerful AOE abilities and plenty of attacks and actions to counteract some of the advantages.

### Rogue 5 only offers Uncanny Dodge

This is likely just not enough. While a great ability, you either give up level 6 druid spells which is much worse hit than level 6 spells or level 3 cleric spells which are also good.

### Comparing Druid 12/Cleric 5/Rogue 3 to Druid 14/Rogue 3/Cleric 3

Access to **Unicorn Spirit** and **Mass Healing Word** and **Disciple of Life** is an incredibly powerful combination that can carry your party all the way through the "mid game". Depending on your party size you might be even able to use some of the mass healing word on your summons.

This will fall off in the "super late-game" as AOEs will get more and more powerful, however, then you can switch off of conjuring and into more healing focused playstyle with **beacon of hope**.

Comment: no exp penalty in 5e?

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier 5e does not penalize multiclassing like previous editions did.

Answer (score 9):

### I would recommend Druid 12/Rogue 3/Cleric 5

If your goals are healing and buffing, then more levels in Cleric would allow you to gain access to their 3rd level spells, some of which are related to buffing and healing (i.e. *beacon of hope* and *revivify*, which are domain spells for you, and *mass healing word*). You will also gain more spell slots by taking more levels in Cleric, which in turn means being able to heal/buff more often.

Furthermore, by taking more levels in Cleric, you also increase the potency of your [Channel Divinity: Preserve Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain)

> As an action, you present your holy symbol and evoke healing energy that can restore a number of hit points equal to **five times your cleric level.**

That said, by not putting more levels into Druid, you will be missing out on *regenerate*, but that's the only spell that suits your intended party role that Druids get at higher levels.

More levels in Rogue will not help you much, although Uncanny Dodge will help *you* to potentially stay alive, but I don't think that ticks enough of your boxes to be worth it. Taking an extra level in Rogue for the ASI is also redundant because you'll then miss out on the ASI at level 12 from Druid. Hence I think it's safe to say that you can ignore taking any further levels in Rogue.

### ASIs

As for *where* to spend your ASIs, I'd max out WIS (higher number of prepared spells for druid *and* cleric, and +1 to any healing spell like *cure wounds*, etc), and with another ASI I'd take a "half-feat" to max out DEX (although it isn't *as* necessary, but if your AC comes from DEX, if you're wearing leather armour for example, then +1 AC makes you slightly more survivable).

Your stats are pretty solid already, to be fair, so I'm not sure what you'd want to do with your other ASIs, maybe pushing CON up to 18? Or taking the Tough feat (that's probably better, since it gives you twice as many HP as taking CON to 18). As [Deeps' answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164434/35259) points out, there are a few other feats that would also benefit your build, such as War Caster, which would help with concentration.

As a crazy option, if you used that second ASI to increase DEX and CHA, then your CHA would be 13 and you'd qualify for the Inspiring Leader feat. Now, your CHA is only going to be at +1, which isn't great, but you would be able to give everyone *some* temporary hit points every so often, which you may consider worth doing. I probably wouldn't, though...